# Chronicle map <-> engine relation

Tags: chronicle, chronicle-map

Really a quick question: I see chronicle Map 3X is moving some of the functionality to Engine product. However Engine itself relies on Map 2X. I am a bit confused how can I use them together? I assume I am missing something but not sure what exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - As you mention above, Currently Chronicle-Engine uses Chronicle-Map 2.
We have no plans ( in the near future at least ) to upgrade Chronicle-Engine to use Chronicle-Map 3. Although, this integration maybe done in the future especially if a paying client requires it.
There is no way to do tcp-replication with Chronicle-Map 3, so if you require tcp-replication, for the moment you will have to use Chronicle-Map 2 or Chronicle-Engine.